# MySQL Stored procedure WHERE

Tags: mysql

Im trying to set procedure for insert row and use the value from parameter to change value in other table. But ...error, and me and Google = no solution...

```
INSERT INTO transakce (`id_transakce`, `akce_uzivatele_id`,            `typ_transakce`, `castka`, `datum_sazky`) 
VALUES (NULL, _akceuzivateleid ,_typ_transakce,_castka, _datum);

SET kreditUzivatele := SELECT ` kredit`  FROM `uzivatele` WHERE  uzivatele.id_uzivatele = _akceuzivateleid ;

SET kreditUzivatele := kreditUzivatele + _castka;
UPDATE `uzivatele` SET `kredit` := kreditUzivatele WHERE uzivatele.id_uzivatele =  _akceuzivateleid ;
```

> One or more errors have occurred while processing your request:
>   The following query has failed: "CREATE DEFINER=`marek`@`%` PROCEDURE `creditCharge`(IN `_akceuzivateleid` INT(9), IN `_typ_transakce` VARCHAR(20) CHARSET utf8, IN `_castka` INT, IN `_datum` TIMESTAMP) NOT DETERMINISTIC MODIFIES SQL DATA SQL SECURITY INVOKER INSERT INTO transakce (`id_transakce`, `akce_uzivatele_id`, `typ_transakce`, `castka`, `datum_sazky`) VALUES (NULL, _akceuzivateleid ,_typ_transakce,_castka, _datum); SET kreditUzivatele := SELECT `kredit` FROM `uzivatele` WHERE uzivatele.id_uzivatele = _akceuzivateleid ; SET kreditUzivatele := kreditUzivatele + _castka; UPDATE `uzivatele` SET `kredit` := kreditUzivatele WHERE uzivatele.id_uzivatele = _akceuzivateleid ; "
>   MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET kreditUzivatele := SELECT `kredit` FROM `uzivatele` WHERE uzivatele.id_uzi' at line 4

Screens:
[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBBSJ.png)
[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7B5u.png)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing the below statement:

```
SET kreditUzivatele := SELECT ` kredit`  FROM `uzivatele` WHERE  uzivatele.id_uzivatele = _akceuzivateleid ;
```

to this:

```
DECLARE kreditUzivatele;
SELECT ` kredit` into kreditUzivatele FROM `uzivatele` WHERE  uzivatele.id_uzivatele = _akceuzivateleid ;
```

or this:

```
DECLARE kreditUzivatele;
SET kreditUzivatele = (SELECT ` kredit`  FROM `uzivatele` WHERE  uzivatele.id_uzivatele = _akceuzivateleid);
```

Comment: MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE kreditUzivatele; SELECT ` kredit` into kreditUzivatele FROM `uzivatele`' at line 6

Comment: Could you please make sure the code snippet posted in the question follows this format -> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html.
Also, could you try moving `DECLARE` bit to be immediately after `BEGIN`